# Prove $\left|e^{\sqrt{-1} t x}\left[e^{\sqrt{-1} a x}-\sum_{j=0}^{n}(\sqrt{-1} a x)^{j} / j !\right]\right| \leq|a x|^{n+1} /(n+1) !$.

Tags: analysis

Prove
$$
\left|e^{\sqrt{-1} t x}\left[e^{\sqrt{-1} a x}-\sum_{j=0}^{n}(\sqrt{-1} a x)^{j} / j !\right]\right| \leq|a x|^{n+1} /(n+1) !
$$
where $t,\,x,\,a\in \mathbb{R}$.

---

We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left|e^{\sqrt{-1} t x}\left[e^{\sqrt{-1} a x}-\sum_{j=0}^{n}(\sqrt{-1} a x)^{j} / j !\right]\right|\\
&=\left|\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(iax\right)^j}{(n+1)!}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{\left(iax\right)^{n+1}}{\left(n+1\right)!}\cdot\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(iax\right)^{j-n-1}\cdot\left(n+1\right)!}{j!}\right|.
\end{aligned}
$$
Then I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Please do not write $\sqrt{-1}$ because it is an ambiguous notation (the square root has two values: $i$ and $-i$).

Comment: By Taylor's theorem with integral remainder, we have $$
e^z  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\frac{{z^j }}{{j!}}}  + \frac{1}{{n!}}\int_0^z {e^t (z - t)^n dt}  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\frac{{z^j }}{{j!}}}  + \frac{{z^{n + 1} }}{{n!}}\int_0^1 {e^{zs} (1 - s)^n ds} 
$$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $n\geq 0$. Can you finish?